# How to reference a custom file in Openshift application using OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR environment variable

Tags: java, jar, cron, openshift

I've created an openshift app called "java" with the following cartridges:

- Tomcat 6 (JBoss EWS 1.0)
- Cron 1.4

I have a pulled the app into my local directory and added directory "lib" and my executable "testapp.jar".

> ..\java\src\main\webapp\lib\testapp.jar

I added a 'minutely' cron job file called "java"

> ..\java.openshift\cron\minutely\java

I successfully committed the directory and the cron file.
But the cron job keeps failing to find and execute the testapp.jar.

I tried the following two scripts:

> java -jar $OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR/src/main/lib/testapp.jar
>
> java -jar $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/lib/testapp.jar

Neither works and I keep getting a message that testapp.jar can't be found.

So clearly, my reference is incorrect.
Apparently, I should be using OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR as it's the only persistent directory.

I would like to ask for help with the cron script as I am not having much luck referencing (executing) my testapp.jar.

Could anyone please give me an example of how to correctly reference reference the testapp.jar using the OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR environment variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR environment variable instead which references the root directory of the application on local machine. It is the directory including .git and .openshift sub-directories.

I created the following minute cron file:

> ..\java.openshift\cron\minutely\java

```
cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR java -jar
$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/src/main/webapp/lib/testapp.jar
```

Now I am able to run a jar file and schedule an execution of the jar file.

One additional note. Make sure to compile the code with jre 1.7 as I was getting an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: App : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 when I compiler the code using jre 1.8.
```

Java OpenJDK 1.7 is used by OpenShift.

[source](https://developers.openshift.com/en/tomcat-getting-started.html):
OpenShift uses JBoss EWS 1.0 and 2.0 for Tomcat 6 and 7 respectively. EWS is a hardened and Red Hat supported version of Apache Tomcat. Both versions use Java OpenJDK 1.7.